# How to POST an image to Twitter by statuses/update_with_media in Lua

Tags: lua, twitter, http-post, twitter-oauth, coronasdk

I have problems building the header and/or body of the http-POST for a Twitter oAuth update_with_media call in Lua.

- I'm using `multipart/form-data` as `Content-Type`
- All `oauth_*` parameters are included in the body, including an `oauth_signature`.
- POSTing to url `https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json`

The problem is I have no idea how to successfully add the image data (media[]) to the body, in addition to 'status' and the other oauth parameters.

Also, how do I calculate the `Content-Length`?

As of yet, I'm constantly getting a 500 Internal Server Error back form Twitter.

Can anyone provide me with a code snippet to add image data (jpg) to a POST? I'm using the Corona SDK btw, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If any help, please refer to this issue:
[Twitter API `status/update_with_media` return `404 Not Found`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613797/twitter-api-status-update-with-media-return-404-not-found)

If your still get the 500 error, please refer to this one:
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1525