# Twitter API `status/update_with_media` return `404 Not Found`

Tags: twitter

My App need to update the status and add images to the update, so the `status/update_with_media` is the best choice. There is no library I can use on my platform, so I ported `PorlarSSL`(a SSL library written in C) and implemented the HTTP protocol on TCP protocol in C. Here is my codes to request the `update_with_media` API.

The TCP send buffer(include the HTTP header and post body) is:

```
POST /1/statuses/update_with_media.json HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Host: upload.twitter.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="wafabKbGRc16RUWgQvD4g", oauth_nonce="UvA44TqLLGWlHy3TDU8BPgAAAAAD", oauth_signature="62FJbljZOk9vOHU7RYCIn%2Fyl68c%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1331134259", oauth_token="46043095-aRPvEBFqHEiDwM0wWURJskAkdrLIJGMLRqI5yx1Po", oauth_version="1.0"
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 659
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--xyz

----xyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media[]"; filename="asddf.gif"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<binary-image-data>
----xyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"

hello word
----xyz--
```

These fields are separated by `\r\n`, the blank line is expect the `\r\n`, so I'm sure the format is correct. The TCP buffer(include the binary image data) then encrypted by SSL and then send to Twitter, but the returned body is a HTML doc, the HTTP header is

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2012 06:16:46 GMT
Set-Cookie: k=10.34.145.134.1331187406993104; path=/; expires=Thu, 15-Mar-12 06:16:46 GMT; domain=.twitter.com
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 21:57:35 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 12882
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: tfe
```

I want to know what this mean? Is the binary image data need to be encrypted by SSL? or the `status/update_with_media` do not need SSL and just HTTP post is sufficient? If the `Content-Length` is incorrect(for example, larger than the actual sending length), will it cause any problem?

My handshake with twitter is OK and I can request other data from Twitter, so my internet is   OK.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which server are you connecting to?  Photo uploads need to be directed to upload.twitter.com.

Additionally, `Content-Disposition: from-data; name="media[]"; filename="asddf.gif"` contains the typo `from-data`.

Comment: Year! you're right, I have setting the `api.tiwtter.com` constantly in my TCP connect parameters, so `api.twitter.com` cannot recognize the `upload.twitter.com`, so server says 404 error.

But when I fix the error, I immediately got a 403 Forbidden error:
`{"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update_with_media.json","error":"Error creating status."}`

Comment: After hours of debugging, I can got the 200 code now, and the image is POSTed to Twitter success. Strictly according to [this issue](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1525), but I sorted the body by `name`. One additional is **Do Not forget the last `\r\n` after the post body**. Thank you A.R.K.

Comment: The extra \r\n is a good tip - I'll have to keep that in mind :)